# What are some recommended plugins for Trac?

Tags: plugins, project-management, trac

In particular, I need a more full fledged version of Trac to support robust project management, and task tracking.  I went through the plugins and literally found over 50 that looked promising.

My question is to the admins/users of Trac: which ones are indespensible for making Trac feature complete and which ones should be avoided *(e.g. stability issues)*?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Lots of Trac plugins look promising. Unfortunately only a handful really delivers and even then some of them are not properly supported or maintained. They also tend to conflict sometimes.

I will not recommend anything for project management specifically but these are the ones which made our live so much easier:

- [TagsPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TagsPlugin) - the most useful one, adds tags support
- [BreadCrumbsNav](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/BreadCrumbsNavPlugin) - show previously visited pages, saves lots of time
- [ShowPath](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/ShowPathPlugin) - show the breadcrumbs path, useful if you have your pages named hierarchically
- [CaseInsensitiveWiki](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/CaseInsensitiveWikiPlugin) - allows entering case-insensitive URLS
- [Stratistics](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/StractisticsPlugin) - show Wiki/SVN statistics
- [WikiRename](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/WikiRenamePlugin) - allows page renaming (does not work well with the Tags)

0.10

- [WebAdmin](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/WebAdmin) - pre-installed in 0.11 but before you need to get it separately

Answer (score 12):

My Favorites:

General:

- Better editor WYSIWYG:   http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracWysiwygPlugin
- TicketCalendar Macro:   http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/WikiTicketCalendarMacro
- AccountManager: http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin

Scrum
 - Agilo: http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AgiloForScrumPlugin

This is the place to watch http://trac-hacks.org/

Comment: Would really help if you could add one line description of why you think its a good plugin.

Answer (score 10):

Besides those already mentioned here, I also found the following necessary:

1. [Announcer](http://www.trac-hacks.org/wiki/AnnouncerPlugin) - very flexible notification scheme
2. [AutocompleteUsers](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AutocompleteUsersPlugin) - handy while typing (existent) user name
3. [AutoLinks](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AutoLinksPlugin) - automatically make words not conforming to wiki naming rule but matches existent page name a link
4. [CustomFieldAdmin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/CustomFieldAdminPlugin) - make manage custom fields easier
5. [Redirect](http://svn.ipd.uka.de/trac/javaparty/wiki/TracRedirect) - handy if you constantly need to make short-hand name wiki pages (like HTML redirects to HyperText .....)
6. [TicketDelete](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TicketDeletePlugin) - make deleting, if at all needed, easier
7. [WikiRename](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/WikiRenamePlugin) - must-have for wiki refactoring

Below are good-to-have:

1. [S5](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/S5Plugin) - directly render wiki pages as slideshow in S5 format, could be really useful for using Trac as the source for presentation
2. [FullBlog](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/FullBlogPlugin) - add blogging support to Trac
3. [Vote](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/VotePlugin) - cool add-on feature for big team
4. [TracWikiToPdf](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracWikiToPdfPlugin) - transform wiki page to pdf dynamically (however the effect might be all that satisfying)
5. [TimingAndEstimation](http://www.trac-hacks.org/wiki/TimingAndEstimationPlugin) - neat for tracking time and/or estimation

Answer (score 9):

I really like the [BatchModifyPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/BatchModifyPlugin) that makes it easy to change more than one ticket at the time.

Comment: Four years later and this functionality has been added to Trac 1.0.

Answer (score 6):

[MasterTicketsPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/MasterTicketsPlugin) is quite useful for ticket dependncies.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend against Bitten for CI (Continuous Integration) (see [Martin Fowler on the subject](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html)) although I am using it.

The task force behind Bitten doesn't seem strong enough to process the remaining tasks. Simply look at the age and the number of posts in [Bitten tickets](http://bitten.edgewall.org/query?status=assigned&status=new&status=reopened&col=id&col=summary&col=status&col=owner&col=type&col=priority&col=milestone&col=time&order=time)

Answer (score 3):

I don't admin our Trac, and I don't know all the plugins we use. But I co-developed a GUI we use to navigate the tickets and to track time spent on specific ones. It uses the **[xmlrpc](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin) plugin** to query ticket information and to write some information back. Extending Trac is really easy this way.

Answer (score 3):

my must-have list of plugins:

- http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin
- http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/GitPlugin
- http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TagsPlugin
- http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/BatchModifyPlugin
- http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TicketDeletePlugin
- http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin

some may be part of trac since 0.12

and a script:

- https://subtrac.sara.nl/oss/email2trac

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Bloodhound](http://bloodhound.apache.org/) is a collection of plugins bundled with Trac. It includes some of the individual plugins suggested in earlier answers, like the [AccountManagerPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin).

The major plugins developed as part of Bloodhound are a very robust [Multi Product implementation](https://issues.apache.org/bloodhound/wiki/Proposals/BEP-0003), [full text search](https://issues.apache.org/bloodhound/wiki/BloodhoundSearch) (based on Whoosh) with better navigation.
[Ticket relations](https://issues.apache.org/bloodhound/wiki/Proposals/BEP-0006) have also just been added.

Bloodhound keeps integrating newly released trac versions quickly, and all plugins interoperate as expected because they're purposefully bundled. It's also still compatible with most [trac-hacks](http://trac-hacks.org/).

Answer (score 1):

What plugins you will consider must-have depends heavily on your use case.

Must-have plugins if you need more power in creating advanced wiki pages:

- [GraphvizPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/GraphvizPlugin)
- [WikiExtrasPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/WikiExtrasPlugin)

Must-have plugins if you like IDE-style auto-completion and indentation features in the text editor:

- [TextareaKeyBindingsPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TextareaKeyBindingsPlugin)
- [WikiAutoCompletePlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/WikiAutoCompletePlugin)

Must-have plugins if you use many Mercurial repositories:

- [MercurialPlugin](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMercurial)
- [HgDirManagerPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/HgDirManagerPlugin)

Must-have plugins if you ...

- ... want to archive emails: [MailArchivePlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/MailArchivePlugin)
- ... want to track time spent on tasks: [TimeTrackingPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TimeTrackingPlugin)
- ... want to plan your week: [WeekPlanPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/WeekPlanPlugin)
- ... want to drag cards between stacks: [CardsPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/CardsPlugin)
- ...

But if you don't have these use cases, you will not find the plugins valuable.